# Any method to document design in xib/Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

You can document your code in ios but is there any way to document design you do in xib/storyboard ?.

I will explain a little more.We have size classes in ios , we add/remove/change constraints according to each size class . After some time we will forget what we have done. So altering the design after that will be very difficult.The case becomes more worse if you are asked to alter a design someone else has done.

So is there any way of documenting the designs like 
why a constrain was added?
Why a constrain was deleted in another size class ?
What will happen is I delete on constrain or change it priority or value ?etc

Comment: Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170788/xcode-and-xib-self-documentation

Comment: that question's answer is mostly about iboutlets and actions . My questions is how to document the constraints and other stuffs